# Non Static Method says its static?

Tags: java, android, class

I tried to use a non-static method in a (for me) non-static method but he only say i cant use a non-static method not in a static...

i don't know what i should try, so i just asked.

Problem in the line

```
public void Rassen(View v){
    Rassen.ContentRassen();
}
```

here is some code:

```
package thetruenerathul.pathfinder001;


import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;


import thetruenerathul.pathfinder001.NewCharacter.Rassen;


import static thetruenerathul.pathfinder001.R.layout.rassen;



public class Pathfinder extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String[] Charakter = new String[3];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pathfinder);
    }

    public void NewCharacter(View v){

        setContentView(R.layout.name);
    }

    public void ContentName(View v){

        EditText Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TfName);
        Charakter[0] = Name.getText().toString();
        setContentView(rassen);

    }

    public void Rassen(View v){
        Rassen.ContentRassen();
    }

    public void ContentZurueck(View v){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pathfinder);
    }

}
```

and the Code of ContentRassen()

```
public class Rassen extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void ContentRassen(View View){

        Rasse(View);
        setContentView(R.layout.klassen);

    }

    private void Rasse(View View){

        Button Rasse;

        switch(View.getId())
        {
            case R.id.BtZwerg:
                Rasse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtZwerg);
                Pathfinder.Charakter[1] = Rasse.getText().toString();
                break;

            case R.id.BtHalbling:
                Rasse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtHalbling);
                Pathfinder.Charakter[1] = Rasse.getText().toString();
                break;

            case R.id.BtElf:
                Rasse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtElf);
                Pathfinder.Charakter[1] = Rasse.getText().toString();
                break;

            case R.id.BtMensch:
                Rasse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtMensch);
                Pathfinder.Charakter[1] = Rasse.getText().toString();
                break;

            case R.id.BtGnom:
                Rasse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtGnom);
                Pathfinder.Charakter[1] = Rasse.getText().toString();
                break;

            case R.id.BtHalbOrk:
                Rasse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtHalbOrk);
                Pathfinder.Charakter[1] = Rasse.getText().toString();
                break;

            case R.id.BtHalbElf:
                Rasse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtHalbElf);
                Pathfinder.Charakter[1] = Rasse.getText().toString();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the method named the same as the class? `CountRassen` isn't static, so you can't do `Rassen.ContentRassen()`... you need an instance of `Rassen`

Comment: I think the keyword you are searching for is 'this' which refers to the current object. Just replace Rasse or Rassen with it

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are accessing the method using class not by object.

If you want to access the method by class name then you need to define that method as static like below

```
public static void ContentRassen(View View){
    Rasse(View);
    setContentView(R.layout.klassen);
}
Rassen.ContentRassen();
```

For non static - you need to create the instance and then call the method using the instance Object